# How to get the bearer token from http request

Tags: java, http, bearer-token

I have the following cUrl command to send reqest to server

`curl -k https://localhost:9200 -H "Authorization: Bearer eH8AIFX6PqyrmJ1cJLC"`

in the server side I need to retrieve the token that is eH8AIFX6PqyrmJ1cJLC.

the line,

`String access_token=request.header("Authorization: Bearer");`

outputs :     **Bearer eH8AIFX6PqyrmJ1cJLC**

But I only want to retrieve **eH8AIFX6PqyrmJ1cJLC**.

How do I do this.

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-

Answer (score 1):

You could use `String.split()` to split the value at the space character and then use the second part.

Or you could just discard the first 7 characters if you know that it will always be "Bearer".

Or you could use `String.replace()` to replace "Bearer " with "".

Answer (score 0):

In general, either the Framework or the http classes you are using should provide a way to get the headers. If the output is not in your wanted format, just parse the output. In your case you could use e.g. `access_token.replace("Bearer ", "")`.